# I would like it to scroll sideways based on the day

Tags: jquery, date, scroll

I have a problem with this script, I would like it to scroll sideways based on the day, how can I do?

```
   var d = new Date();
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="lunedì";
weekday[1]="martedì";
weekday[2]="mercoledì";
weekday[3]="giovedì";
weekday[4]="venerdì";
weekday[5]="sabato";
weekday[6]="domenica";

if(d == weekday[1]) { $( ".table-responsive" ).scrollLeft( 300 );}

  else if (d == weekday[1]) { $( ".table-responsive" ).scrollLeft( 300 );}
  else if (d == weekday[2]) { $( ".table-responsive" ).scrollLeft( 450 );}
  else if (d == weekday[3]) { $( ".table-responsive" ).scrollLeft( 600 );}
  else if (d == weekday[4]) { $(".table-responsive" ).scrollLeft( 750 );}
  else if (d == weekday[5]) { $(".table-responsive" ).scrollLeft( 900 );}
  else if (d == weekday[6]) { $(".table-responsive" ).scrollLeft( 150 );}
```

Comment: please add your completely code into a snippet

Comment: `d` will never equal a string

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to check out `getDay()`:

> The `getDay()` method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where `0` represents Sunday. For the day of the month, see `Date.prototype.getDate()`.

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  console.log(d.toString(), "Day: " + d.getDay());
  var weekdays = [
    "lunedì",
    "martedì",
    "mercoledì",
    "giovedì",
    "venerdì",
    "sabato",
    "domenica"
  ];

  function toUpperFirst(str) {
    return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
  }

  $.each(weekdays, function(i, day) {
    $("<th>").html(toUpperFirst(day)).appendTo($(".table-responsive thead tr").eq(0));
  });

  var view = $(".viewport");
  switch (d.getDay()) {
    case 0:
      // Sunday / Domeniza
      console.log("Scroll to Domeniza");
      view.scrollLeft(900);
      break;
    case 1:
      // Monday / Lunedi
      console.log("Scroll to Lunedi");
      view.scrollLeft(0);
      break;
    case 2:
      // Tuesday / Martedi
      console.log("Scroll to Martedi");
      view.scrollLeft(150);
      break;
    case 3:
      // Wednesday / Mercoledi
      console.log("Scroll to Mercoledi");
      view.scrollLeft(300);
      break;
    case 4:
      // Thursday / Giovedi
      console.log("Scroll to Giovedi");
      view.scrollLeft(450);
      break;
    case 5:
      // Friday / Venerdì
      console.log("Scroll to Venerdi");
      view.scrollLeft(600);
      break;
    case 6:
      // Saturday / Sabato
      console.log("Scroll to Sabato");
      view.scrollLeft(750);
      break;
  }

  view.scroll(function(event) {
    console.log($(this).scrollLeft());
  });
});
```

```css
.viewport {
  width: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-responsive {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 1050px
}

.table-responsive th {
  width: 150px;
}

.table-responsive td {
  height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="viewport">
  <table class="table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>150</td>
        <td>300</td>
        <td>450</td>
        <td>600</td>
        <td>750</td>
        <td>900</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really expecting d to be a day name, you could use an object to lookup the scroll position.

By Name:

```js
  const dayName = 'giovedì';

  const positions = {
    domenica: 150,
    lunedì: 300,
    martedì: 300,
    mercoledì: 450,
    giovedì: 600,
    venerdì: 750,
    sabato: 900
  };

  $( ".table-responsive" ).scrollLeft(positions[dayName]);
```

By Number

```js
  const dayNumber = 0;

  const positions = [300, 300, 450, 600, 750, 900, 150];

  $( ".table-responsive" ).scrollLeft(positions[dayNumber]);
```

Create a function and use a default value:

By Name or Number

```js
  const positions = {
    domenica: 150,
    lunedì: 300,
    martedì: 300,
    mercoledì: 450,
    giovedì: 600,
    venerdì: 750,
    sabato: 900
  };
  const positionsByNumber = Object.keys(positions).map(k => positions[k]);
  const defaultPosition = positionsByNumber[0];
  /**
   * n name of weekday or number
   */ 
  const setTablePosition = n => {
    const position = (
      positions[n] || 
      positionsByNumber[n] ||
      defaultPosition
    );

    $( ".table-responsive" ).scrollLeft(position);

    return position;
  }
```

Results:

```js
setTablePosition('mercoledì'); // 450
setTablePosition('fubar'); // 300
setTablePosition(0); // 150
setTablePosition(12); // 300

// And by users clock
setTablePosition((new Date()).getDay());
```

Comment: this seems to me the most correct, only how do you know the current day?

because according to the day the table has to scroll to take the view of the day.

Comment: Thats up to you. Are they clicking on the name of the day; are you checking local time? You can see the comment about `(new Date()).getDay()` to get it from local time.

Comment: Also @jacoposilvestri the day names and positions are off. Sunday is actually the first day and 300 is repeated across two days. If you need those indexes that is another issue.